# find site, app pool and recycling schedule using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the below format printed for few of our servers:
[serverName]|[siteName]|[appPoolName]|[appPoolState]|[appPoolRecycleSchedule]

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
$Pool = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools

foreach ( $p in $Pool )
{
    $app_pool = $p.Name
    $timing = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\\AppPools\$app_pool -name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
    Write-Host "$($compName)|$($app_pool)|$($p.state)|$($timing.value)"
}
```

How do I get the site name in here?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working - thanks to a whole bunch of websites!.

```
$Pool = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools

foreach ( $p in $Pool )
{
    $app_pool = $p.Name

        $apps = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[`
            @applicationPool='$app_pool']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).ItemXPath 

    $site = ''
    foreach ($s in $apps) {
        $name = $s -replace "\/system.applicationHost\/sites\/site\[\@name='", ""
        $name = $name -replace "' and \@id='\d{1,10}'\]\/application\[\@path='", ""
        $name = $name -replace "'\]",""
        if($site -eq ''){
            $site = $name
        }
        else{
            $site = $site + ", " + $name
        }
    }

    if($site -eq "")
    {
        $site = "NotFound"
    }

    $timing = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\\AppPools\$app_pool -name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
    Write-Host "$($compName)|$($app_pool)|$($p.state)|$($timing.value)|$($site)"
}
```